# The context menu does not work in Visual Studio 2005 (win7)

Tags: visual-studio, ide, development-environment

When I select a class, variable etc that should have a context menu in vs2005 and right click on it does not open up the context menu. I can use the context menu key on the keyboard to activate the menu but not the mouse.  If I right click on any white area a context menu will show, but that does not make any sense for me i.e. there is nothing selected and the menu are there for irrelevant for the class, method or whatever was previously selected.

My Environment is as follow:

- Win7
- Visual Studio 2005 professional sp1
- Running in a Virtual environment (Virtual box under Ubuntu 9.04)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us a bit more information here?

- What language are you working in?
- Does the problem reproduce in other languages?
- What type of application are you working on?
- Does it still happen if you create a new application?

I can't think of anything off hand that would cause this behavior although it is extremely odd.  I think the first step to try and resolve this issue is to reset the settings of VS.

> devenv.exe /resetsettings

If that doesn't work I would try repairing the installation via the Add / Remove Programs menu.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the suggested solutions and get back.